# how to call cross-domain web api using ajax?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, wcf-web-api

```
jQuery.ajax({
           type: "GET",
           url: 'http://example.com/restaurant/VeryLogin(username,password)',
           dataType: "json",

           success: function (data) {
               alert(data);
           },
           error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
               alert("error");
           }
       });
```

it alerts success, but data was null. The url returns xml data, if we specify the dataType we can get the json data,but here it was not getting any data.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

Javascript is subject to the same domain policy.  This means for security a JS Script in a client browser can only access the same domain as it came from.

JSONP is not subject to the same restrictions.

Check the jQuery docs on JSONP here:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Here is a working example of using JSONP to access a cross-domain service via JQuery AJAX:

http://jsbin.com/idasay/4

And just in case JSBIN deletes this paste in the future:

```
jQuery.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: 'http://api.geonames.org/postalCodeLookupJSON?postalcode=6600&country=AT&username=demo',
     dataType: "jsonp",
     cache: false,
     crossDomain: true,
     processData: true,


     success: function (data) {
         alert(JSON.stringify(data));
     },
     error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
         alert("error");
     }
 });
```

Comment: i have already followed the link,but it didn't produced the result.

Comment: From the link posted previously:
"    Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject to the same origin policy; the request can not successfully retrieve data from a different domain, subdomain, or protocol.
    Script and JSONP requests are not subject to the same origin policy restrictions."

Comment: I would advise looking at how to achieve what you need using the JSONP example at the above link.

Comment: i tried jsonp also but no result. If i replace an url that produces the json data directly without specifying the content means adding url+&json,i'm getting the response.But not getting any for the xml response.

Comment: If you request jsonp, you won't get any xml in the response, you'll get JSON.  xhr.responseText should contain the returned JSON.

Answer (score 2):

It's impossible to use `Ajax` to get cross-domain data directly without changing backend. It's called [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

You can set the special header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in backend([how do to this](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/)). Or you can use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).

Answer (score 0):

Look for jsonp datatype.

```
jQuery.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: 'http://xxx.com/restaurant/VeryLogin(username,password)',
       dataType: "jsonp",
   cache: false,
       crossDomain: true,
   processData: true,

       success: function (data) {
           alert(data);
       },
       error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
           alert("error");
       }
   });
```

Comment: i followed your changes nut no result yet.

Comment: You must read about jsonp. Yet, the page you are calling is not returning jsonp data.

Answer (score 0):

here is a fantastic article to make GET and POST cross-domain call :
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

It just helped me a lot....shoot comments for any query.